# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was trying to understand the working of HibernateTemplate in Spring-hibernate environment. Since I am new to HibernateTemplate, I feel difficult to understand the errors. In my project I have used all the jar files availabe in **spring-framework-4.0.3** and **hibernate-4.3.5**. Some of the additional jars used in this project are:

```
*cglib-nodep-2.1.3.jar
*commons-logging.jar
*ojdbc14.jar
*tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar
```

Following java/xml files were used :

**StudentDaoInterface.java**

```java
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import model.Student;

public interface StudentDaoInterface {

    public int save(Student st);
    public boolean update(Student st);
    public boolean delete(Student st);
    public Student findbyPK(int pk);
    public List<Student> findAllUsingHQL();
    public List<Student> findAllUsingCriteria();

}
```

**StudentDaoImplHT.java**

```java
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;

import model.Student;

public class StudentDaoImplHT implements StudentDaoInterface {

    private HibernateTemplate ht;

    public void setHt(HibernateTemplate ht) {
        this.ht = ht;
    }

    @Override
    public int save(Student st) {
        int i=(Integer)ht.save(st);
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Student st) {
        ht.update(st);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(Student st) {
        ht.delete(st);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Student findbyPK(int pk) {
        Student st = (Student)ht.get(Student.class,pk);
        return st;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> findAllUsingHQL() {
        List list = ht.find("from student"); 
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> findAllUsingCriteria() {
        DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Student.class);
        List list = ht.findByCriteria(dc);
        return list;
    }

}
```

**Student.java**

```java
package model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student",schema="system")
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;

    public Student(int id, String name, String email, String address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">  
    <bean id="bds" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="system"/>
        <property name="password" value="manager"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="15"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="5000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sf" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="bds" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>model.Student</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ht" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sf" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="dao.StudentDaoImplHT">
        <property name="ht" ref="ht" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**SaveClient.java**

```java
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import dao.StudentDaoInterface;
import model.Student;

public class SaveClient {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        ConfigurableApplicationContext cap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/test.xml");
        StudentDaoInterface dao = (StudentDaoInterface)cap.getBean("dao");
        Student st = new Student(222,"bbb","bbb@gmail.com","hyd");      
        dao.save(st);
        System.out.println("success");
        cap.close();
    }


}
```

After running the code **SaveClient.java** I face following errors:

```java
Dec 17, 2017 9:27:52 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3f8f9dd6: startup date [Sun Dec 17 09:27:52 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 17, 2017 9:27:52 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/test.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sf' defined in class path resource [resources/test.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at test.SaveClient.main(SaveClient.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptorInternal(BeanWrapperImpl.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.isWritableProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`. But in [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.18.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html), it says that the following, so be careful about your Spring version or decrease your Hibernate from 4.3.5. to 4.2 or 4.1 as documentation suggests.

This variant of LocalSessionFactoryBean requires Hibernate 4.0 or higher. Note that this version is not compatible with the (the quite refactored) Hibernate 4.3 yet; please upgrade to the **Spring 4.0 line for full Hibernate 4.3 support**. We recommend using this version with the latest Hibernate **4.1.x or 4.2.x** releases.

Comment: As per your suggesstion, I have changed name to "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean". I have also used jar files from **hibernate-4.1.2** and **spring-framework-4.1.6**. Problem mentioned above got solved. But I am getting **org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException**. Error stack trace is as follows:.

Comment: I cannot see the stacktrace but, could you please accept and upvote my answer since your problem is solved, and ask another question regarding your new problem. Than i'll look onto that. Thank you

Comment: stack trace : 


 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1135)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:620)

Comment: Could you please ask this in another question and write the link here, there i can answer your question?

Comment: Please answer this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853516/org-springframework-dao-invaliddataaccessapiusageexception-in-hibernatetemplate